# Trouble unit testing onClick method using Mocha Chai and Enzyme

Tags: unit-testing, react-redux, mocha.js, enzyme, chai

I'm having trouble with unit testing using mocha, chai and enzyme for the following. I can't seem to understand how to unit test methods in components and how to unit test `onClick` methods will call those methods. 
The following is what I am trying to unit test:

```
<Link to="/create-new-template-results" onClick={this.checkLink}>
    <Button
        buttonname="Next_button"
        variant="primary"
        label="Save"
        onClickMethod={() => this.submitTemplateCreation()}
        disabled={!this.disabledButtonCheck()}
    />
</Link>
```

.

```
Header: '',
Cell: value => {
    return (
        <div>
            <img
                height={34}
                src="https://content.usaa.com/mcontent/static_assets/Media/icon-trash.svg"
                onClick={() => this.removeAttribute(value)}
            />
        </div>
    );
}
```

.

```
removeAttribute = value => {
    this.props.change('templateAttributeForm', value.original.name, '');
    this.props.removeAttributeItem(value.index);
};

submitTemplateCreation() {
    let profLvlData = Object.values(this.props.templateAttributeFormData);
    let attrData = Object.keys(this.props.templateAttributeFormData);
    let attributeProfLvl = attributeProfLvlUtil(attrData, profLvlData);
    let templateCreationJSON = templateCreationPOSTFilter(attributeProfLvl, this.props.templateFormData);
    this.props.submitTemplateCreation(templateCreationJSON);
}
```

Comment: please annotate the 3 parts of code and what exactly do you want to test (what expected behaviour)

Answer (score 0):

Chai provides some nice tools for testing things exactly like what you are talking about.

You'll want to render your component somehow in the virtual DOM, either by using enzyme's "shallow" or "mount" functions.

Once you've done that, you can access the component using .find, and "simulate" an event using .simulate like so.

```
wrapper.find('Button').at(0).simulate('click');
```

This will find all of the 'Button' components in your wrapper, take the first one, and simulate a click. From there you can use expect() combined with any of the ways Chai provides to examine the state of the component in order to test that your button did what it was supposed to.

Since it seems like you are particularly interesting in the calling of the onClick function itself, I will add that you can specifically check to see if a function is called by doing the following with Chai.

```
expect(MyComponent.prototype.myOnClickFunction).to.have.property('callCount', 1);
```